# Azure B2C API Connector fails with http: 400 There was a problem processing your request. Please try again

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I've connection issues between Azure B2C API Connector and a CAPTCHA Web-Service.
Everything worked well until 31.12.2021. Not sure about the first week in January 2022.

All services, whenever offered by Microsoft are in a Swiss data center. Since January I'm playing Mail Ping-Pong with the MS Support Team :-(

- Azure B2C calling a service via Azure Front Door **in detection mode** fails.
- Azure B2C calling a the service "direct" works.
- Calling the service using Postman works via the Azure Front Door and Direct

I don't use custom policies, so no logs. Or maybe I don't know where to look?
Azure unfortunately only returns a HTTP 400 with the message "there was a problem".
The Service is not receiving any get request.
According to the Firewall log, no request is blocked.

Would be happy for any hints. My personal best guess - Microsoft did renew the X.509 SSL certificates and forgot one due to the 31.12.2021

But would be happy for anything else that might had changed?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Did you check AFD logs? Can you reproduce the issue and provide the correlationId found in the HTML DOM?

Comment: Of course we can reproduce the error. Logs are empty. Seems like the network connection between AD and AFD is not happening at all. I attach a screenshot as I don't know where to find a correclationID.

Comment: In the developer console, click elements tab. At the top in the html content is the correlationId, note this. Then reproduce the issue, and then provide the correlationId.

Comment: <!-- CorrelationId: 8a2fbe38-ef96-4217-8b75-04d298c62809 --> <!-- DataCenter: DB3 -->

Comment: Your API is returning HTTP 302 `A redirect status code of 302 was returned for a request that does not allow redirects.`

Comment: Interesting, the routing type (Front Door) is set to "FORWARD" and postman does not get a 302. The firewall itself should return a 200 if blocking anything.

Comment: Share your POSTMan request. I notice when I send bogus data to your api, I get a 302. Check AFD logs for 302 responses.

Comment: I cant share the request as this would disclose the credentials. You should get a 401 without the correct ?code parameter. In case of bogus data, it would be a 400 Bad Request. But you should never get a 302. And I cant reproduce this. POST: curl --location --request POST 'https://... with ?code Param and Basic Auth. Header

Comment: You can share a request with some bogus data. Check your API&AFD logs for 302’s.